# How to use a custom .png image inplace of caret in a bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap

This is my current code

Action
                
                Another Link

This uses default caret in the drop down menu, but I want to replace the default caret with for an example arrow down.png.

How to get this done, searched the official documentation (https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/#btn-dropdowns-split) but no help.

Comment: Your current code isn't showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Use `img` tag with in span

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <div class="dropdown">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="padding:6px 6px">Button
<span><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-arrow-down-b-512.png" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;"></span>
                                </button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="">Modify</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">Delete</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
```